# Wouldn't the if statement in this PHP function be useless?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am trying to work on someones code and ran into this.

```
private function getAttImages($limit, $forumIds = 0, $fidsReverse = false, $topicIds = 0, $membersIds = 0, $order = 'attach_date', $sort = 'desc', $group = null)
    {
        $fids = '';

        if ($forumIds)
        {
            $r = '';
            if ($fidsReverse)
            {
                $r = ' NOT ';
            }

            if (is_array($forumIds))
            {
                $forumIds = implode(',', $forumIds);
            }

            $fids = ' AND forums_topics.forum_id ' . $r . ' IN (' . $forumIds .  ')';
        }
```

function continues to other things.  However, the question is that first if statement if($forumIds) wouldn't it be useless if every time this function is called $forumIds is set to 0 ?

Comment: The $forumsIds = 0 means to default to 0 if nothing has been passed at that position in the function args. So by default, yes. But they intended it to be overwritten. That way you can just call the function getAttImages(2) without passing all the args.

Comment: See the "Default argument values" section of http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: forumIds is default set to 0, this is not secure to rely on it :)

Comment: Thank you. I am new to php so this helps.

Comment: @Tim - do you have documentation stating the security issues here? This is a pretty common practice (not saying I don't believe you, just I never heard anyone identify default arg vals as a security hole)

Comment: Do you want to check if forumIds is not equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **default value** for this function if nothing else is specified. It means that if nothing is entered when calling the function, it will default be `0` and the function will essentially do nothing.

### Examples:

`getAttImages(5, 1)`
Will essentially set `$limit` to 1 and `$forumids` to 1. The rest of the parameters will be set to their default values as nothing is entered ( `$fidsReverse = false, $topicIds = 0, $membersIds = 0, $order = 'attach_date', $sort = 'desc', $group = null` )

The only required parameter is limit as it has no default value in it. So, at minimum the function can be called like so:

`getAttImages(0);` and the rest will just default to the values defined in the function. However, this code won't do anything as `$forumIds` will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

No. $forumIds is set to zero in the function parameters, but that zero is only applied to $forumIds if someone calls the function but does not explicitly set a value for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
..., $forumIds = 0, ...
```

is setting up the **default** for that variable. It can be overridden with any value when called, but will default to 0 if no value for `$forumIds` is provided.

See the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default.